# There are rip-off sites that blatently copy the stack exchanges?

Tags: discussion

I created this question on Superuser:

[Cannot resolve hostname "raspberrypi" on home network](https://superuser.com/questions/943678/cannot-resolve-hostname-raspberrypi-on-home-network/943757#943757)

I'm still having trouble, so I'm searching the net and I stumbled across this page, which is a literal copy/paste of my question:

http://serverquestions.com/questions/j749/cannot-resolve-hostname-raspberrypi-on-home-network

Is this phenomenon known to the stack exchange admins?  Is this OK?  Should something be done about this?  If so, what?

Comment: [Updated procedure for reporting SCRAPERs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200177)